Disk analyzer error area
Error in disk analyzer, the program shows that 24 GB are free. I start downloading a 15 GB file, download for 3 hours, download 13.5 GB, after which I get an error that there is no space, and the download is canceled. How much longer, why can't I download the information I need to my disk??? Time after time, I see there is space, I download, but there is no space!!!!

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is not answerable in its current form. Which OS and version are you using? Is it an internal or external disk? How is the disk formatted, ext4, ntfs, exfat, fat16, fat32 or something else? Edit your question and add these information.

If this is an external disk and one that you thought was a nice cheap price, it could be a fake - set to report x-amount of space when it really doesn't have that much storage capacity at all. I suppose this could be true with internal disks. Their firmware will report false information to the OS.

Hi! Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, SSD in my laptop, disk formatted ext4

Can you append to you question:  What tools you are using to download with; The result of the command 'df'' before & after the download.

I used Google Chrome and downloaded the zip file
